# Gstreamer - too much delay while listening to RTP stream

Tags: c, gstreamer, rtp, opus

I am new to Gstreamer and I want to use it to listen to RTP stream.

To do that, I use this pipeline :

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps=application/x-rtp port=5000 ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! alsasink
```

I don't know why, but I have some delay (~ 1s) and I want to minimize it.
I'm sure that this is not coming from source and transport.

If anyone has any ideas :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

If anyone has the same problem, this is the properties that helped me :

- `latency` of rtpjitterbuffer
- `buffer-time` and `latency-time` of alsasink

And also update gstreamer :)

Answer (score 0):

try playing with the latency setting on the jitter buffer, eg.

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps=application/x-rtp port=5000 ! rtpjitterbuffer latency=250 ! rtpopusdepay ! opusdec ! alsasink