# GStreamer audio RTP streaming delay exceeds 10 seconds

Tags: gstreamer, embedded-linux, rtp, pulseaudio

I use the following **GStreamer** commands to capture audio on one device **(NXP imx6q)** and send by **RTP**, the other device **(NXP imx6q)** receives the audio stream and playback it.

```
# Capture
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc provide-clock=false volume=0.5 ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=16000,formats=S16_LE ! rtpL16pay ! udpsink host=192.168.3.254 port=5000 sync=false

# Playback
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)16000, encoding-name=(string)L16" ! rtpL16depay ! audioconvert ! pulsesink volume=2 sync=false
```

When I start the above commands before network is ready, the delay of audio playback will exceed to 10 seconds (sometime even 1 minute) sometimes. It seems that the audio frames have been buffered and doesn't drop by **UDP(?)** or other **GStreamer** elements? So should I add `rtpjitterbuffer` to playback according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40721679/gstreamer-too-much-delay-while-listening-to-rtp-stream) or are there any other properties of **GStreamer** elements that I should set?

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `rtpjitterbuffer` will only help with ensuring that all the packages are either received in the correct order or that no duplicate packages are present.

You could try adding a queue with `max-size-buffers=2 leaky=2` this means that it will only push the newest buffers:

`gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc provide-clock=false volume=0.5 ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1,rate=16000,formats=S16_LE ! queue max-size-buffers=2 leaky=2 ! rtpL16pay ! udpsink host=192.168.3.254 port=5000 sync=false`

You could also play around with the `udpsink`'s `buffer-size` property, since a lower value might drop older buffers.

Comment: Removing `sync=false` in both commands solves the problem.

Comment: From this [post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/one-problem-about-one-property-of-udpsink-in-gstreamer/83605), it seems that `sync` property should have not effect to `rtp audio stream` (which should be live source?). So I don't know the reason.